# What is this strange component? (Photo)

Tags: components, identification

On an old board I have found a strange component with seven wires going in/out. I was wondering if someone can help identifying its function.

[image]

Comment: Looks like some sort of transformer.

Comment: It is an old hybrid transformer possibly used in telephony or data for full duplex.

Comment: Its identifier, T302, indicates it's a transformer.

Comment: Braided leads indicative of electrostatic shields, spring clips suggest ferrite core, so my guess it's a high frequency switching transformer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a ferrite core flyback transformer to generate a high voltage DC supply.

The driving circuitry including the ancient germanium AD139 power transistor is on the right and you can see what looks like rectifiers and some filter components on the left. The transformer leads on the left (secondary) are sleeved, and the ones on the right (primary) are just bare enamel wire (and thick). The yellow parts on the left are film capacitors.

Perhaps mid-to-late 1960s era.